# Reading and displaying information from .txt files using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have an idea in my ahead about a website I would like to create. Just want to quickly say that I have experience with PHP, HTM and CSS, at the basic/intermediate level but I am MORE than willing to increase my knowledge of these languages. For my university project I made a website that collects information from different websites and puts them on mine, using the languages i just said above.

So anyway, the Idea is, I play a game called of League of Legends, its a very popular online MOBA game. The game is heavily revolved around a 5v5 game mode, its just 10 individual players, you pick a character, and you go and fight eachother on a map. There are a few things players are interested in, how many many games they have played with a certain character, or how many games they have played with a certain player (you can play with friends, invite them to a game etc.).

So, i'd like to bring this idea to life, did a little digging around in the game folder, and found game logs, within these logs I found this [image: screenshot of game log file]

The redline is the champion (character the person plays) and the black line is the actual players in game name, (it says Human player because there is a game mode for people to play against pre-programmed bots)

The basic idea of the website is that the user directs the program to the game files (a bit like how when you upload a image, you go through folders etc to get to the image etc), the program reads the game log files, variables, champion name, and player name. Then have a counter and display the numbers, like this:

> Champion 1: 200 games.
>
> Champion 2: 10 games.
>
> Player X: 300 games played with these person.

What do people think? How can I go about developing this idea of mine.

TL;DR want to make a program that counts the amount a time a person has played with a champion and with another player.

Comment: PHP has  a [readfile function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). Or you can just use the [file function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Although, I would think it would be a better idea to use a database (since this is PHP). Making writing and reading data much easier.

Comment: If you're talking about the reading to and writing from a file please read file handling from php manual

Comment: So the website can read the logfile of LoL and show statistics on the game. Does it have to be PHP? you could use readfile as stated above, and then use explode to split each line up into words that you can then analyze, like if the first word in the resulting string is "spawning" or "hero" then the line is probably worth using more etc.

Comment: @Gnurgen Im not limiting myself to PHP/cURL, i'm open to learning a new language if it is more suited to the project.

Comment: Well if you make it in something like java people would have to install it and all, i can see the ease of use if its just a website. Maybe something like javascript would work well, i dont know it myself(ill stick to java) but i know people can make some pretty cool stuff with that, like visual representations of the gathered data.